# Java Parse arraylist to an object

Tags: java

Below is my code for updateMovie. I wish to ask how do I parse back an ArrayList back to the object after I update a value in that specific entry. Or otherwise, is there any other implementation where I can update an entry from a .txt file based on the code below.

```
public static void updateMovie() throws IOException
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList al = MovieDB.readMovies(filename) ;
    ArrayList movie = new ArrayList();
    int elementMovieID;
    int confirmUpdate=0;
    int index = 0;
    String value;
    Movie [] m2;

    int MovieID; 
    String MovieName; 
    String MovieReleaseDate;
    String MovieType;
    String MovieRating;
    String MovieStatus;
    String MovieDuration;

    try{
        System.out.println("Enter MovieID to Update: ");
        elementMovieID = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < al.size() ; i++) {
            Movie m1 = (Movie)al.get(i);
            System.out.println("Movie ID: "+m1.getMovieID());
            System.out.println("Movie Name: " + m1.getMovieName() );
            System.out.println("Movie Duration: " + m1.getMovieType() );

            if(elementMovieID==m1.getMovieID()){
                movie.add(m1.getMovieID());
                movie.add(m1.getMovieName());
                movie.add(m1.getMovieReleaseDate());
                movie.add(m1.getMovieType());
                movie.add(m1.getMovieRating());
                movie.add(m1.getMovieStatus());
                movie.add(m1.getMovieDuration());
                System.out.println("Enter the index to edit (1: Movie Name): ");
                System.out.println("1: Movie Name: " + m1.getMovieName() );
                System.out.println("2: Movie Release Date: " + m1.getMovieReleaseDate() );
                System.out.println("3: Movie Type: " + m1.getMovieType() );
                System.out.println("4: Movie Rating: " + m1.getMovieRating() );
                System.out.println("5: Movie Status: " + m1.getMovieStatus() );
                System.out.println("6: Movie Duration: " + m1.getMovieDuration() );
                index = sc.nextInt();
                for(int j=0; j<movie.size(); j++)
                {
                    if(index==j){
                        System.out.println("Please Update: ");
                        value = sc.next();
                        movie.set(j, value);
                        System.out.println(movie);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        MovieDB.saveMovies(filename, al);
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException > " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please follow Java Naming Convention and let your variables begin with a lowercase.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to do a lot in this method.  Methods should be very simple and strive to accomplish just one task.

Comment: Please elaborate more on your requirement

Comment: Also if you are using java version > 1.4 then use generics, example `List<Movie>`

Comment: Please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: To elaborate on my earlier point, a method called `updateMovie()` shouldn't be a zero-argument method that fetches what should be arguments via `IO`.  The `IO` should be handled elsewhere, and then that data sent to the `updateMovie` method as arguments.  Then the `output` of the updated movie should also be it's own method, even if the method `updateMovie` CALLS that method to confirm the update.  Moreover, your method declares SEVERAL variables that aren't being used anywhere in the method unless I'm just blind.  Isn't your compiler warning you about these unused variables?